# get user info from a client certificate in a java web service context

Tags: java, security, web-services

I'm developing a java web service, with client certificate security enabled. 
I don't want to add a parameter to each method with a user ID. Since the user is already authenticating through the soap header with his client certificate, is it possible to fetch the user data (common name, email, etc) from his certificate?

Thanks!

Comment: did you manage to get it working? Share feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can retrieve DN from the request,

```
      Object certChain = request.getAttribute(
            "javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
       if (certChain != null) {
          X509Certificate certs[] = (X509Certificate[])certChain;
          X509Certificate cert = certs[0];
          String n = cert.getSubjectDN().getName();
        }
```

For this to work, you have to configure the HTTPS connector properly. If AJP is used, you have to configure the AJP connector so the certificate is passed from Apache to Tomcat.

Comment: thanks for the reply!
I had to stop working on this code but I will come back here ASAP and try out your suggestions.

Comment: You are must correct, sir! Thanks!
I tried for some time the WebServiceContext, but with no success because of application server versions.
I just add the "request" code:
Object certChain = oracle.security.jazn.ApplicationServerProxy
                                 .getHttpServletRequest().getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");

Answer (score 0):

Cast your `java.security.cert.Certificate` to [`java.security.cert.X509Certificate`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html) and check the methods you have available on it - like `getSubjectDN()`